# For loops in Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, for-loop, teradata, teradatasql

I'm trying to understand how to use FOR loops in Teradata SQL. I used the very same example that you find in Teradata documentation

```
FOR CustCursor AS c_customer CURSOR FOR
  SELECT CustomerNumber
        ,CustomerName
    FROM Customer
DO
  SET hCustNbr = CustCursor.CustomerNumber;
  SET hCustName = CustCursor.CustomerName;
  DELETE FROM Customer WHERE CURRENT OF c_customer;
END FOR;
```

Using one of my test tables named `Customer_Offer` which has two columns (Customer and Offer) I tried to do

```
FOR CustCursor AS c_customer CURSOR FOR
  SELECT Customer
        ,Offer
    FROM Customer_Offer
DO
  SET cust = CustCursor.Customer;
  SET o = CustCursor.Offer;
  SELECT cust, o FROM Customer_Offer WHERE CURRENT OF c_customer;
END FOR;
```

But no matter which statement I use in this example, I always get `Failed [3706 : 42000] Syntax error: expected something between the beginning of the request and the 'FOR' keyword.`
What am I missing?

Comment: FOR loops are only allowed within a Stored Procedure.

Comment: @dnoeth can you please explain a little bit more? If that's so, how can I use it?

Comment: Why do you want to use a for loop?  SQL is set based, there are very few, if any, instances where a loop is better.  Regarding stored procs, teradata has documentation and examples.  Your example is from the stored proc documentation.